# sum of integers in a string using lambda

Tags: python, lambda

I am trying to use lambda function to add up all the numbers. I am getting following error,

> Syntax error - "Generator expression must be parenthesized if not sole
>   argument"

```
def solve(s):
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x + int(y) for y in s if y.isdigit(),s)

print solve('1o2i212')
```

It works if I use the following.

```
def solve(s):
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, [int(i) for i in s if i.isdigit()])

print solve('1o2i212')
```

Comment: If you want to get _seriously_ functional, you could do `sum(map(int, filter(str.isdigit, s)))`. ;) I realise that you're practicing use of `lambda`, but `sum(my_iterable)` is easier to read (and more compact) than `reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, my_iterable)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python 3 users should do a `from functools import reduce`. `reduce` has been moved out of builtin functions from Python 3.

```
return reduce(lambda x, y: x + int(y),(y for y in s if y.isdigit()),0)
```

**output**

```
8
```

**Explanation**

```
lambda x, y: x + int(y),        #x is the aggregating sum
(y for y in s if y.isdigit()),  #reduced over all the digits in s
0                               #x=0 the starting sum value.
```

To understand reduce, check [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) it needs a starting seed of 0 to avoid conversion errors

If you do not give a starting value:-

```
>>> def solve(s):
...     return reduce(lambda x, y: x + int(y),(y for y in s if y.isdigit()))
... 
>>> print(solve('1o2i212'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in solve
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <lambda>
TypeError: must be str, not int
```

If you do not want to give a starting value for the aggregation do the below:-

```
return reduce(lambda x, y: x + y,(int(y) for y in s if y.isdigit()))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That is all I need.

Comment: The syntax of reduce takes and optional third parameter as initializer, which when provided is "placed before the items of the iterable in the calculation, and serves as a default when the iterable is empty" [from the doc]

>> reduce(function, iterable[, initializer])

In above, you can remove the initializer if it is like:

>> reduce(lambda x, y: x + y,(int(y) for y in a if y.isdigit()))

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution using [List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

```
def solve(s):
    return sum([int(c) for c in s if c.isdigit()])
print(solve('1o2i212'))
```

Solution using [functools.reduce](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) (Python 3):

```
import functools
def solve(s):
    return functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x + int(y),[y for y in s if y.isdigit()],0)
print(solve('1o2i212'))
```

N.B.: 0 is the initializer which is an optional parameter of `functools.reduce`.

> If the optional initializer is present, it is placed before the items
>   of the sequence in the calculation, and serves as a default when the
>   sequence is empty.

Output:

```
8
```

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to use lambda to understand how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Note: Python 3 developers need to use:

```
from functools import reduce
```

The signature is `reduce(function, iterable[, initializer])`

So, you can decompose as follow:

```
def solve(s):
    function = lambda x, y: x + int(y)
    iterable = (c for c in s if c.isdigit())
    initializer = 0
    return reduce(function, iterable, initializer)

print(solve('1o2i212'))
```

You get 8.

Here, *iterable* is a generator object. 
And notice that *initializer* is required because the default value is `None`.

Of cours you can put all things together with parenthesis.

```
def solve(s):
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x + int(y), (c for c in s if c.isdigit()), 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to understand some things before working with lambda :

How lambda syntax works ;

```
lambda x,y:x+y   #this is lambda function
```

Now we will pass the argument to this lambda , there are two ways to passing argument first one :

```
arg=lambda x,y:x+y
print(arg(1,2))
```

Second method :

```
print((lambda x,y:x+y)(1,2))
```

Now if we use reduce with lambda then the syntax is :

```
print(reduce(lambda x,y:x+y,[1,2,3,4,5]))
```

So if you are passing a generator expression what should be your lambda syntax:

```
print(reduce(lambda x,y:x+y,(generator expression)))
```

and what is your generator expression is:

```
(y for y in s if y.isdigit())
```

let's put in lambda syntax:

```
print(reduce(lambda x,y:x+y,(y for y in s if y.isdigit())))
```

ok now we don't need print because we are using function and returning the result so:

```
def solve(s):
    return reduce(lambda x,y:x+y,(y for y in s if y.isdigit()))

print(solve('1o2i212'))
```

when you will run this program you will get :

```
12212
```

Because we are adding strings and when you do str(`1`) + str(`2`) it is `12` in python not `3` so what we have to correct is convert the str to int there :

```
def solve(s):
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, (int(y) for y in s if y.isdigit()))

print solve('1o2i212')
```

Now the output is :

```
8
```

So which mistake you were doing :

Your generator expression is wrong because you are mixing with generator expression output with lambda parameters :

```
(int(y) for y in s if y.isdigit())  #this is correct
```

so change this :

```
reduce(lambda x, y: x + int(y) for y in s if y.isdigit(),s)
```

to this :

```
reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, (int(y) for y in s if y.isdigit()))
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a ton for your explanation.

Comment: One minor correction - def solve(s):
    return reduce(lambda x,y:x+y,(y for y in s if y.isdigit())) for the output to be  12212. Thought of adding it.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this should actually be enough for the problem.

```
solve = lambda x: sum([int(i) for i in x if i.isdigit()])
solve('1o2i212') #8
```

Comment: Agreed. Then I don't need lambda for the same, I could rather use what @arsho suggested.

Comment: Right. It honestly doesn't matter too much what you use in the end, this is just the simplest implementation I could think of. Good luck!

Comment: I am with you, My intention was to practice the use of lambda reducer function. Thanks anyways.

Comment: I deleted my answer as it matches with this.